# Access PHP object content programmatically, even in deeper levels

Tags: php, arrays, object

accessing object content within PHP works fine when you only set a single level like this:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->name1 = 'value1';
$param1 = 'name1';
echo $obj->$param1; // echoes values1 as expected
```

But what if I need deeper object content like this (w/o transforming it into an array first or similar stuff...)

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->name1->name2 = 'value2';
$param2 = 'name1->name2';
echo $obj->$param2; // does not echo value2 obviously
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You meant echo $obj->$param1 and echo $obj->$param2 I guess (dynamic attribute name, you skipped the $ sign)

Comment: Just use an array... There is absolutely zero use for the `StdClass` above. Using `StdClass` doesn't make you code magically OOP. If it looks like an array, you are going to use it as an array: use an array.

Comment: @MaGnetas you are right, I've added these

Comment: @PeeHaa it's a matter of performance _not_ to transform it into an array first. there must be solution for case 2 above, or? I usually totally agree on the array part, but here, I would really prefer solve OOP like to save exec time. ;)

Comment: You do not "transform" it into an array. You just declare an array. Nothing to transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First approach (simple):**

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->name1->name2 = 'value2';
$param1 = 'name1';
$param2 = 'name2';
echo $obj->$param1->$param2;
```

**Second approach (more generalized):**

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->name1->name2 = 'value2';
$params = 'name1->name2';

$value = $obj;
foreach(preg_split("/-\>/",$params) as $param)
    $value = $value->$param;

echo $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* just parse the `$param2` string and print out the value at the end:

```
$result = $obj;
foreach( explode( '->', $param2) as $var) {
    $result = $result->$var;
}
echo $result;
```

But... I don't see why you wouldn't use an array for this.

Comment: @LZNPDE - And in what other manner would it be used to make it more efficient?

Comment: I meant to agree with you, but say that I imagine that using explode and then iterating would be less efficient than just iterating an array... kk3003 mentioned something about performance above, then again he also mentions not transforming it into an array, which is what explode does, but anyway...